# Restkit request dynamic mapping

Tags: ios, xcode, http, post, restkit

I'm using RestKit for posting objects to the server. In my object I have two properties: `name` and `socialId`.

I want to send to server only properties that have data.

If `name != nil` send:

```
{
   "name" : "name",
}
```

If `socialId != 0` send:

```
{
   "socialId" : socialId,
}
```

But RestKit sends all data. For example:

```
{
   "name" : "",
   "socialId" : 0,
}
```

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to using [RKDynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:]

You should check representation properties in block and add attributes mapping for desired properties.